# Conditional expectation and Rao Blackwell

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expectation, parameter-estimation

Consider a family of densitites $f(x,\theta)=\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{x})}{\theta}$. Let $X_1$ be a single observation from this family. I have shown that $\sqrt{X_1}/2$ is an unbiased estimator. Now consider $n$ observations $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. I have shown that $T(X)=\sqrt{X_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{X_n}$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$. Now use the Rao Blackwell theorem to find an improved estimator.

The improved estimator is $E(\sqrt{x}/2\mid T)$. For this I need the conditional density. How do I find this?

Thanks

Comment: Only one function $f(\ ;\theta)$ can be a density at present. There must be a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function $x\mapsto\dfrac{\exp(-\sqrt{x})}{\theta}$ is not a probability density on $(0,\infty)$ unless $\theta=2$.  Here's a guess: Maybe you meant $\dfrac{\exp\left(-\sqrt{x/\theta\, {}}\right)}{2\theta}$.

At any rate, suppose you have i.i.d. observations, and you want
$$
\mathbb E\left(\frac{\sqrt{X_1}}{2} \mid \sqrt{X_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{X_n}\right).
$$

You know
\begin{align}
\frac {\sqrt{X_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{X_n}} 2 & = \mathbb E \left(\frac{ \sqrt{X_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{X_n}}{2} \mid \sqrt{X_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{X_n}\right) \\[15pt]
& = \mathbb E\left(\frac{\sqrt{X_1}}{2} \mid \sqrt{X_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{X_n}\right) + \cdots\cdots\cdots \\[10pt]
& {}\qquad \cdots\cdots + \mathbb E\left(\frac{\sqrt{X_n}}{2} \mid \sqrt{X_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{X_n}\right).
\end{align}
By symmetry, all of the terms on the right must be equal to each other, so each must be equal to $1/n$ times the term on the left.

Comment: Perfect and clear!

Comment: I ve been looking at your answers I am not getting how to compute conditional expectation sometimes. I am not sure how do we get this step after you said "you know"
\begin{align}
\frac {\sqrt{X_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{X_n}} 2 & = \mathbb E \left(\frac{ \sqrt{X_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{X_n}}{2} \mid \sqrt{X_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{X_n}\right) \\\end{align}

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache Hes not active on site can you please help me ?